# How to delete record in FMDB swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, fmdb

I'm using `FMDB` library.

I want to delete a record but I got this error:

```
2017-06-23 22:54:18.406 kashanmap[6347:80664] DB Error: 1 "near "LocationInfoFa": syntax error"
2017-06-23 22:54:18.406 kashanmap[6347:80664] DB Query: delete LocationInfoFa where id = ?
2017-06-23 22:54:18.407 kashanmap[6347:80664] DB Path: /Users/sm_emamian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3B1D7BBE-63F3-4D5A-96CB-E9DCA7AE1B98/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5AE23770-99AB-4F07-A45F-BB508B54602C/kashanmap.app/kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db
----->>>>>>>>>>>>Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "LocationInfoFa": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near "LocationInfoFa": syntax error}
```

my query:

```
        let db = database
        let q = try db?.executeUpdate("delete \(table) where id = ?", values: [id])
```

Comment: `table` is a variable.

Comment: Duh. I might have a reason for asking, don't treat me like an idiot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `delete` is not legal SQL. You mean `delete from`.